# What is the best place to store garlic in the kitchen?

Tags: garlic, kitchen

I've been at a friend's house. When I looked for the garlic I the fridge my friend said garlic doesn't go in the fridge. But another friend said garlic lasts longer if placed in the fridge, even when it hasn't been peeled and placed in plastic foil / film.

What's the best place to put garlic in the kitchen and why?

Comment: What is the climate/weather like at that place? What is the average temperature in the kitchen?

Comment: Generally speaking, where you buy food in a store is a good indication of how to store it at home.  If you buy something in the refrigerated section, you store it in the fridge, etc.  Most vegetables are pretty happy being stored at room temperature.

Comment: Except many bottles and cans must be stored in the fridge once opened.

Answer (score 6):

Keep your garlic away from the refrigerator, or any cold storage. Garlic germinates after exposure to cold, which is why it's planted in autumn. This means that putting your garlic in the refrigerator is a bad idea as it will cause it to sprout, which creates undesirable changes in flavor and texture.

The garlic you buy at the store has been cured (dried) and will last for months at room temperature, and that's the best place for it to be. Garlic pots are better than sealed containers because they have holes that allow airflow, keeping the garlic from getting soggy while protecting it from sunlight or other strong light. I grow garlic and make my own garlic strings and braids, which I hang in my kitchen, I always make sure they are hung somewhere out of direct sunlight, but if I wasn't putting them out for show I would keep them in a cool, dark cupboard.

Here's a picture of my garlic pot, although there are many designs out there.

[image: Garlic pot]

Comment: This is a good point, I will add that. Although I make my own garlic strings and hang them, I do keep them out of direct sunlight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please post a picture of a garlic pot. I have no idea what this is.

Comment: I've added a picture of mine @JackMaddington, there are other designs but they all follow the same principle.