# How long does it take garlic to germinate in the fridge?

Tags: garlic

If left in the fridge, how long does garlic take to germinate? I have experienced the green sprouts in the past, and was able to chop them off and eat the remaining garlic. I am curious add to how long that takes as I cannot remember.

This way I will know how much garlic to keep in the fridge at my friend's house, based on how much is used per week, since my friend insists that it must be kept in the fridge.

If I plant the garlic that has germinated in a pot, will it grow? How do you grow it?

Comment: there are quite a lot of questions about garlic at gardening.se, where that's more on-topic. I grow it from supermarket garlic but you can't always.

Comment: I also suggest that you ask at least one of your questions on gardening.se. As I see it, you have two other questions. I recommend that you break this question down to only ask one question per question posted, but, we may end up answering all of your questions 'cause we're squirrelly that way.

Comment: On your previous question asked yesterday  **http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/79229/what-is-the-best-place-to-store-garlic-in-the-kitchen**  the answer was specifically and correctly stated as garlic should **not** be stored in the fridge. If you care about your garlic ( and it appears you do ) why would you ignore the excepted wisdom of not storing your garlic in the fridge?

Comment: The last line / paragraph is a question for Gardening SE, and it indeed [is already answered there](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/will-garlic-that-sprouted-on-the-shelf-produce-new-cloves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Germination of garlic is a gradual, slow process, and how long it takes depends a lot on how close to sprouting the garlic was when you originally bought it. Seems to me it would have to sprout *faster* at room temp, than refrigerated, anyway.

I routinely keep garlic in the fridge (shame on me!), and sometimes the garlic will keep in the fridge for at least a month without sprouting (That's about how fast I use it, so I don't have data past a month). On the other hand, I have seen nubby little green/purplish sprouts (abt. 3mm long?) on garlic which I had *just* purchased; cut them off; garlic was fine - just like your experience.

I guess the reason you want to keep the garlic in the fridge during your stay at your friend's house is to avoid unnecessary rancourous arguments - yes? So here's the thing: your friend may be wrong, but for the layman, it's not a huge deal to keep the garlic *in* or *out of* refrigerator, as he likes.